# How to import an existing database in my Django project?

Tags: python, django, database

I'm trying to add an existing sqlite3 database to my Django project but it doesn't seem to be recognized.

I've added that database to my project folder, modified the settings.py file to reflect that addition:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'added_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'added_db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I then ran the 'python manage.py makemigrations' and the 'python manage.py migrate' commands but it doesn't seem to do anything. When I run 'python manage.py inspectdb', it only shows the tables within the default database.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you read about migration --fake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Depends on document:**

> The migrate management command operates on one database at a time. By default, it operates on the default database, but by providing the --database option, you can tell it to synchronize a different database.

So, you must provide your db name when you make migrate.For detail you can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/)

`./manage.py migrate --database=added_db`

Comment: Thank you Sir, it seems to have worked! Just one question though. Following the migration, 0001_initial.py file has been generated. If I want to retrieve data from my db, do I need to create a new model in models.py by using the code generated in this file? Or will the model be created automatically anyway?

Comment: If your model is same, you don't need to define your model again, but if it changes based on databases, you must define it.